# evento on click en react

Tags: json, reactjs

mi pregunta es como hacer que un evento un click saque un item de un json en concreto, que cada que de un click en un nombre me aparezca el mismo nombre

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

si doy click en valor: 1 me mande el mismo nombre en un log y no lo eh podido conseguir
 [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi codigo es el siguiente

```html
class App extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      names: []
    };
    
    axios.get("http://localhost:3001/names")
    .then(response => {
      this.setState({
        names: response.data
      })
    })
    .then(error => {  
      console.log(error);
    })
  }

  handleClick = (name) => {
    console.log('this is:', {name} );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div> 
     
        <ul>
        {
          this.state.names.map( name =>
          <li key={name} onClick={this.handleClick}>{name}</li>)
        }
        </ul>
        
    </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: handleClick = (name) => {
    console.log('this is:', {name} );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div> 
      
        <ul>
        {
          this.state.names.map( name =>
          <li key={name} onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this,name)}>{name}</li>) 

QUEDA ASI :)

Answer (score 1):

Primero necesitas *atar* el evento al componente. Es algo raro, pero acostúmbrate a añadir los eventos así:

```
<li key={name} onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}>{name}</li>
```

La alternativa a hacer esto es, desde el constructor definir el evento:

```
constructor(props){
  super(props);

  this.state = {
    names: []
  };

  axios.get("http://localhost:3001/names")
    .then(response => {
      this.setState({
      names: response.data
    })
  })
  .then(error => {  
    console.log(error);
  })

  //Aquí:
  this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
}
...
{/* Así puedes dejar el evento como lo tienes tú*/}
<li key={name} onClick={this.handleClick}>{name}</li>
```

Esto solo asegurará que el evento sea el correcto (la función handleClick recibirá en el parámetro `name` la información del evento). Para enlazar el dato que quieres debes usar

```
<li key={name} onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this, name)}>{name}</li>
```

o

```
<li key={name} onClick={this.handleClick(name)}>{name}</li>
```

o usando el operador de flecha:

```
<li key={name} onClick={(e) => this.handleClick(name, e)}>{name}</li>
```

dependiendo de dónde prefieras hacer el `bind`.

Referencia: https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html

Comment: Si de hecho despues vi la ducoumentación y es como lo mencionas, muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿No se supone que las arrow function no utilizan el this? Apenas ando aprendiendo, así que no estoy segura.